# Why is the same texture rendering on all objects?

Tags: rendering, texturing

Its a very simple scene that I'm trying to render, the first one I've got this far with at least.  There is a spinning globe in the center with 2 images imported as planes.  In the object view window everything looks fine when I play the animation but when I render the plane images take on the texture of the globe.  I'm not sure how to get the planes to display the right texture in the render. Thanks for any help!

https://www.dropbox.com/s/dy0aia237rp9fz6/globe%20logo.blend?dl=0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe in the *Properties* panel > *Render Layers* > *Layer* > *Material*, click on X to close the selected material

Comment: i cant believe it was that simple, i spent hours trying to find an answer.  thank you!